# Deleting multiple objects on Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've got a semi-complex method to delete 3 different kinds of ParseObjects on my Parse.com backend. Here's the block of code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> findQuestions = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_QUESTIONS);
    findQuestions.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_QUESTIONS_BELONGS_TO, quiz.getObjectId());
Log.d("KMH", "findQuestions Query starting for quiz: " + quiz.getObjectId());
    findQuestions.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> questions, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("KMH", "findQuestions Query returned...");
                for (ParseObject question : questions) {
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> findAnswers = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_ANSWERS);
                    findAnswers.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_ANSWER_BELONGS_TO, question.getObjectId());
                    Log.d("KMH", "findAnswers Query starting for question: " + question.getObjectId());
                    findAnswers.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> answers, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.d("KMH", "findAnswers Query returned...");
                                for (ParseObject answer : answers) {
                                    answer.deleteInBackground();
                                }
                                Log.d("KMH", "findAnswers Query done!");
                            } else {
                                Log.d("KMH", "Parse error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    question.deleteInBackground();
                }
                Log.d("KMH", "findQuestions Query done!");
            } else {
                Log.d("KMH", "Parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            quiz.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d("KMH", "Quiz deleted!");
                        getQuizzes();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("KMH", "Parse error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Now, the logic behind this is that, given a quiz object ID, it runs a query and gets the questions related to that quiz. And then, after finding that List of questions, for each question in the list, it runs a query to find it's associated answers. For each answer in the list, it deletes the answer object, and then deletes the question object. Once that's done for every question in the list of returned questions, it deletes the quiz object that all the questions are related to, and ends by calling `getQuizzes();` to refresh the list.

I have confirmed the quiz objectId is being passed correctly.

```
10-31 02:25:41.901  29950-29950/me.kevinhaube.quizme D/KMH﹕ findQUestions Query starting for zR7GaOtwgk
10-31 02:25:42.061  29950-29950/me.kevinhaube.quizme D/KMH﹕ findQUestions Query returned...
10-31 02:25:42.221  29950-29950/me.kevinhaube.quizme D/KMH﹕ Quiz deleted!
```

As you can see, the Log statements for findAnswers don't get called. It also doesn't call the "findQuestions Query done!" Log statement. So it's something in the execution of this method that is messing me up. Neither the questions, nor the answers are being deleted.

Any ideas?

**ANSWER:** I was calling the question query in the Category class of my back-end on Parse, and not the Questions class. Oops!

Comment: The code formatting is very difficult to read, but I do notice that in the callbacks, you do not [test if `ParseException e` is null or not](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/DeleteCallback.html#done(com.parse.ParseException)).

Comment: Good catch, and formatting has been fixed...sorry about that!

Comment: I threw the if(e==null) statements in, and no error messages were returned, but the same three Logs still printed, and nothing else.

Comment: I also just noticed that you don't get the "findQuestions Query done!", which strongly suggests that [`answers` is null](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/FindCallback.html). Please check all your `ParseException`s! Also, `if(e!=null)e.printStackTrace();`, please.

Comment: It turns out `questions` is null, causing `answers` to be null as well, and thus deleting the `quiz`. Not too sure why it's returning null, but this is progress!